# Detect when user stops touching the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Project

Hi,
I'm struggling with `GestureDetector` in Flutter. What I want to do is extremely simple: get the vertical drag distance of an user input.
I managed to do this with this sample code

```
  int scrolled = 0;

  ....

  GestureDetector(
    onVerticalDragUpdate: (d){
      scrolled += pos;
    },     
    //TODO reset scrolled when finger leaves the screen  
  ),
```

#### Problem

Problem is that I want to detect when user finger leaves the screen in order to reset the scrolled `variable`. Using `onVerticalDragEnd` won't do the trick beacause it's fired even when user stop scrolling and the finger is still on the display.

So I started to analise the behaviour of other all `GestureDetector` callbacks, searching for some solution but even `onTapUp(), onPanEnd()` do the same

What am I missing? 
Thanks

Comment: I think that you should use `onPanUpdate` instead.

Comment: In what way? How can I detect when finger leaves? On pan update gives me no control on that

Comment: Use `onPanUpdate` instead of `onVerticalDragUpdate` and then use `onPanEnd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Listener` to detect every touch input.

```
final touchDetector = new Listener(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onPointerUp: (_) => resetScroll(),
  child: child,
);
```

Comment: It didn't work with me